# InstallShield 2009 Support Files/Billboards with multiple files

Tags: installshield

I need to execute the microsoft visual studio redistributable 2005 and 2010 as a prerequisite. I added the two files in Suport Files/Billboards section:

[image]

But now, I don't know how to run the distributables files. In a older version where only ran the 2005 version I saw the line in the install script file:

```
// Install the Visual C++ 2005 SP 1 Redistributable Package
LaunchAppAndWait ( SUPPORTDIR ^ "vcredist_x86.exe", "\q", WAIT );
```

What I have to do to run the two redistributable files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably want /q instead of \q. To run two files, copy that line and change the file name in the quoted string.

Comment: So I can not run two files with the same name in different folders?

Comment: I misread; thought you had _x86 and _x64 redists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LaunchAppAndWait` (or better yet `LaunchApplication` these days) can handle two files in two folders fine, but the support files view does not. You can either rename them; place them in folders next to setup.exe and use something like `PACKAGE_LOCATION`; or download them at install time with `XCopyFile`.

If you're using a recent enough version of InstallShield, you can instead use prerequisites in an InstallScript project which will just handle these details for you. I forget quite when that was added. InstallShield 2009 is pretty old now.